# Drag and Drop images from one gallery to another Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, gallery

I have a requirement in my app to drag images from one Gallery to another Gallery. Is that possible to implement? Can someone provide me with some sample code. Also I am trying to implement this in android 2.x so i cannot use the OnDragListener or other classes used for dragging in android 3.x . Thanks for help!